# Is there a HashMap join elements

Tags: java, join, dictionary, hashmap

Is there a simple function for joining all elements and key values, to a String

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("lebron", "james");
m.put("kevin", "durant");
```

m.join(",") should produce: "lebronjames,kevindurant"

I'm looking for a simpler (less verbose) solution using guava or apache common (StringUtils) Java libs, instead of iterating over the map

Comment: Why `lebronjames` and not `lebron:james`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using **Google [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)**:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
m.put("lebron", "james");
m.put("kevin", "durant");

Joiner.MapJoiner joiner = Joiner.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("");
System.out.println(joiner.join(m));  // return lebronjames,kevindurant
```

Comment: If you're already planning to use Guava, this is unambiguously the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
String mapString = m.toString();
String newStr = mapString.substring(1, mapString.length() - 1).replaceAll("=", "");
```

This relies on the behavior of [AbstractMap.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString%28%29). I've never been quite comfortable relying on `toString` implementations.

So I would prefer to iterate the list. And in fact the iteration is also very brief:

```
for (String key : m.keySet())
   newStr += key + m.get(key) + ",";
newStr = newStr.substring(0, newStr.length() - 1);
```

Edit with whatever `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` code you like.

Comment: Ideologically, it's a very, very bad practice. But nevertheless, a brilliant answer. +1 for sure.

Comment: I used StringUtils join, fot Lists, isn't there somthing similar, or is Java so poor?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, if you use a `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
m.put("lebron", "james");
m.put("kevin", "durant");

String result = m.reduce(1, (k, v) -> (k + v), (r1, r2) -> r1 + "," + r2);
```